# return value of a model.save on BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have function on the Backbone view:

```
onRender: function() {
      this.ui.form.on('submit', function() {

        mylogin = new login();

        valid = mylogin.save({boxid:$("#boxid").val(),password:$("#passwordid").val(),validate:true});

        if(valid != false)
        {
               vent.trigger('navigate', 'home');
        }

        return false;
      });
```

and this function on the model:

```
validate: function(attrs, options){
    if(attrs.boxid.length < 10)
      {
        return false;
      }
   else if(attrs.password.length < 10)
      { 
        return false;
      }
   else
      {
        if((attrs.boxid!=myBoxid)||(attrs.password!=myPassword))
        {
          return false;
        }
        else
        {
        return true;
        }
      }
```

I want to trigger this `vent.trigger('navigate', 'home');` when the validation is correct, but it doesn't work, any idea? what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'valid' returning false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a very common mistake in your assumption about how backbone `validate` works. If your validation function returns anything, that is an indication of an error. So...for one thing, you're backward on that. You're returning false when validation fails, and you should be returning a message as to why it failed. Also when you do `validate:true`, that's not an option you're passing there, you're actually setting an attribute on your model named validate. Options are passed as a second object.

Read these docs carefully: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

Try doing something like this. Sorry without more information this is the best I can do to help. Cheers.

View:

```
onRender: function() {
  this.ui.form.on('submit', function() {
    mylogin = new login();

    mylogin.save({
      boxid:$("#boxid").val(),
      password:$("#passwordid").val()
    });

    if(!myLogin.validationError) {
      vent.trigger('navigate', 'home');
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

Model:

```
validate: function(attrs, options){
  if(attrs.boxid.length < 10) {
    return "user id must be more than 10 characters";
  } 

  if(attrs.password.length < 10) {
    return "password must be more than 10 characters";
  } 

  if((attrs.boxid!=myBoxid)||(attrs.password!=myPassword)) {
    return "Your login credentials are incorrect";
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really seem to work, when the user enters the right credentials nothing happen, and the problem is that the page reload and I cannot check if the `myLogin.validationError` has something in it

Comment: Try, `if(!myLogin.validationError)` with the `!` I may have misunderstood what you wanted to do. If that works I'll edit the answer.